# Weird Wordpress / HTML / CSS Behavior

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I'm hoping someone will be able to shed some light on this.  I have a mockup I did in HTML and CSS that allows for a menu treatment.  When you hover over a menu item (represented by a single image), it overlays the image with a slightly transparent div and some text that describes the option (for example an image of a question mark, when hovering over it, an overlay will appear that says "Information" or something to that effect).  This all works perfectly.

I've now imported this exact same HTML and CSS into a php template to use in Wordpress.  The CSS hasn't changed at all and the HTML output looks the same (obviously some of the HTML is dynamically generated by Wordpress but the output in the browser is the same).  However, now when you hover over the image, the div is appearing directly to the right of the image, rather than on top of the image.  Here's the HTML and relevant CSS:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            <img src="images/diary.png" />
            <div class="tab-content">View the Diary</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            <img src="images/family.png" />
            <div class="tab-content">Woodman Family</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            <img src="images/history.png" />
            <div class="tab-content">Historical Context</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            <img src="images/about.png" />
            <div class="tab-content">About the Project</div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    width: 41%;  
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#menu .tab {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 23%;
    border-left: 3px solid #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#menu .tab img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.tab-content {
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 24%;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: rgba(86, 81, 65, .8);
    display: none;
    transition: all 1.2s;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#menu .tab:hover > .tab-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My theory is that there must be something in Wordpress that is interfering but I can't find anything via the element inspector in Chrome. Any ideas would be greatly helpful.  I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Offhand, I would suggest that the `position:relative` should be on the containing anchor link (since that is what is being 'overlaid') not the overall parent div. Positioning context is important.

Comment: That said, to my mind, you should be using background images on the anchors since the images (it would appear) are not actual **content**. You can then fade the text in and out in hover with no positioning required at all.

Comment: So I tried both of those things and they present different problems.  In the static HTML, the image is no longer centered within the anchor (it seems to position into the bottom right) and the semi-transparent overlay is now gone (although the text still appears in but it is no longer centered).

Comment: In Wordpress, the hover doesn't produce the text at all (so no overlay AND no text), except for the last item in the list which produces it off to the right. My assumption is that the other overlays / text are appearing underneath the other images but to the right of the actual image. So position: relative on the anchor (instead of the outer div) didn't fix the problem at all.